# Can't set Station only mode of esp8266 arduino

Tags: c, arduino, esp8266

When in `WIFI_AP` mode all goes well, but when in `WIFI_STA` mode it is still in `WIFI_STA_AP` mode.

How do I set the WiFi to station only with no software access point available.

```
  if(wmode == "AP") {
     Serial.println("Starting in AP mode");
     WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
     WiFi.softAP(ssid, pwd);
     WiFi.softAPConfig(charToIPAddress(ip), charToIPAddress(gateway), mask); 
  } else if (wmode == "STA") {
     Serial.println("Starting in STA mode");
     WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
     WiFi.begin(ssid, pwd);
     WiFi.config(charToIPAddress(ip), charToIPAddress(gateway), mask);
  }
```

EDIT: this is not about `wmode`, this code's `if` statement works fine, re: arduino String class operator (shorthand)

Comment: What's the definition of `mode`?

Comment: oh thats irrelevant... just an internal String classed variable, set to "AP" or "STA" only.

Comment: yea but unless you know the ESP8266 arduino code..... you won't know about the dual STA_AP operation of the device and how to turn it off.

Comment: Have you tried calling `WiFi.disconnect();` and `WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);`? That's in the code I use to switch between AP and STA mode, and it works great every time.

Comment: @Daniel Minion Worked great! Post a replay and i'll tick ya.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you - Summarised my theory into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ESP8266 seems to OR the mode parameter when you use WiFi.begin instead of just setting it, and also remembers what mode is it was in previously (Through reboots, for example). Calling `WiFi.disconnect();` followed by `WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);` should explicitly tell the ESP to disable all currently running WiFi operations - Be it infrastructure mode, or AP mode - And then you can define what mode it should be.